# Sandbox Solutions on a SharePoint VM that also acts as a Domain Controller

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have dozens of 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Execution Worker Process Proxy' processes running.  A new one seems to appear every 10-15 seconds until my memory is completely spent.

I'm running Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012 SP2 and SharePoint 2013 Server SP1.

I see the following errors in the ULS:

> An unhandled exception was caught when trying to activate the worker
>   process proxies.  Exception caught was
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Process has exited,  so the
>   requested information is not available.      at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)      at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ProcessName()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.CreateWorkerProcessProxies().
>
> Error activating the worker process manager instance within the worker
>   process.
>   - Inner Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Process has exited,  so the requested information is not available.      at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)      at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ProcessName()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWorkerProcess.CreateWorkerProcessProxies()

I've set the logging for the User Code Service to Verbose and followed all the steps on these pages:

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/08/error-the-sandboxed-code-execution-request-was-refused-because-the-sandboxed-code-host-service-was-too-busy-to-handle-the-request.aspx)

[TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3b50dd8b-d789-4a2d-86f2-784b0e73c6a8/foundation-many-spucworkerprocessproxyexe-processes-and-high-memory-load?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: Your running SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server on a domain controller?!?!

Comment: Just a development VM  =P

Comment: Even for development, its a bad idea... A DC is not a regular server, and even for dev purposes, should always be stand alone.

Comment: I have to second what @MattBear says.  Especially with the proliferation of virtualization, cramming a bunch of server roles onto a single OS for development purposes is just inviting headaches, and doesn't provide any real benefit.  Split the services up across VMs so you can isolate where the problem is, and make your troubleshooting/debugging less of an exercise in masochism.

Comment: User Profile Sync, and Document Conversion wont work in this scenario. SQL and SharePoint use local groups, a DC cannot have local groups.

Comment: Giving a bunch of developers multiple VMs does not cut it for many organizations.  We have successfully done single VM senarios up until 2012 R2 and SP 2013 SP1 (including 2012 with SP 2013). The VMs have thus far successfully synced from AD to UPS through the sync service without issue.  I cannot speak for Document Conversion.

Comment: I eventually gave up and created a 2 VM Farm.  What a horrible waste of resources...